# Error con raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.7

Necesito calcular la transformada de Laplace. Para eso usé el siguiente codigo:

```
from sympy.abc import x, s
from sympy import Symbol, exp, cos , sin , Heaviside, integrate, limit, oo

x=Symbol("x")
s=Symbol ("s")
f=raw_input(" write any function : ")
integral= integrate( exp(-s*x) * cos(3*x) ,(x,0,oo), conds="none")
print integral
```

El problema es que al tener `f` con `raw_input`, cuando el usuario ingresa el codigo `f` toma valor de string por lo que me tira error.

Este es un ejemplo si f toma el valor de

```
f=3*x
```

me dice:

> ```
> integral= integrate( exp(-s*x) * f ,(x,0,oo), conds="none")
> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'exp'
> ```

¿alguna idea de como arreglar esto?

Comment: Hi this is spanish site, edit your question or ask in [SO]

Comment: gracias, ahi lo edite!

Answer (score 3):

Efectivamente, se debe a que `raw_input` retorna una cadena y se espera una expresión. La solución es parsear la cadena a una expresión sympy válida. Para eso podemos ayudarnos de [sympy.parsing.sympy_parser](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/parsing.html):

```
from sympy.abc import x, s
from sympy import Symbol, exp, cos , sin , Heaviside, integrate, limit, oo
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

x=Symbol("x")
s=Symbol ("s")
f= parse_expr(raw_input(" write any function : "))
integral= integrate( exp(-s*x) * f ,(x,0,oo), conds="none")
print integral
```

**Salidas de ejemplo:**

> write any function : x*3
>   3/s**2
>
> write any function : cos(3*x)
>   s/(9*(s**2/9 + 1))

Se puede **usar `input`** en vez de `raw_input` pero **esto debe evitarse siempre que sea posible**: `input` evalúa cualquier expresión Python válida, por lo que habilitamos al usuario a que ingrese cualquier código Python y haga lo que le dé la gana con el sistema. Usar `input` (o `eval` en Python 3) es exponerse a ataques de inyección de código sin necesidad y es una mala práctica si puede evitarse.

Como ejemplo tonto, nada impide al usuario ingresar algo como `os.system('rm -rf /')` y cargarse los archivos del sistema si tenemos la mala suerte de haber importado `os` en nuestro módulo....

Answer (score 1):

Puedes poner una función que transforme el valor a integer

```
def convertStr(s):
try:
    ret = int(s)
         except ValueError:
    #Try float.
         ret = float(s)
return ret
```

Castear el Raw Input directamente a  un int

`int(raw_input(""))`

Aunque yo utilizaría la función Input, ya que con ella puedes evaluar lo que el usuario introduzca como parámetro de entrada

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers